# Call to a member function getAction() on a non-object

Tags: php, netbeans, laravel, laravel-4, xdebug

Hi there i followed these instructions (http://pietervogelaar.nl/php-xdebug-netbeans-vagrant/) to get `XDebug` up and running with `vagrant`  and `NetBeans`. 
It now works .... almost.

Anytime i run a code that fire a breakpoints, `NetBeans` works fine allowing me to do my debug thing with no problems.

The thing is at the end of the request Laravel will always return that error : 
Call to a member function `getAction()` on a `non-object`, specifying a code location that 
`looks weird : xdebug:/­/­debug-eval:1.`

Even stranger, my page is rendered and the html is here, but the standard laravel error page is rendered also, at the end of my own page ......

Of course if i disable my breakpoint, everything runs just fine.

My versions right now :

**Apache :**
`Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Apr 17 2014 21:49:25`

**PHP :** 

`PHP 5.4.28-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: May  5 2014 09:32:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans`

Comment: The error self explains it self. We can't help you like this.

Comment: Hi Daan, i know this problem is quite special, just tell me what u would need and i'll provide.

Comment: You're trying to call getAction() from a non-object so somewhere you're calling `$object->getAction();` I need a `var_dump` from object `var_dump($object)`

Comment: Thanks for your help,  i'm using Laravel so here is what i'm going to do. First i'm going to searchj for "getAction()" in the code i have written myself, then i will do the same  on the framework code. The fact the view is fully rendered before the error takes place  gives me quite a precise idea about where that getAction should be ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i finally found it. 
Problem doesn't come from XDebug or Php or Laravel.
Problem comes from Netbeans.

I had an expression in my watch list i wasn't using anymore.
Deleting every custom entries in the watch list just solves the issues.

Hope at some point it helps someone else ....