# xdebug 2.4.0 php7.0, crash after breakpoint

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

i have a problem during the debugging of php pages.
When i set a breakpoint, the debugger stop on the line, but when i click f8, f7, or f5 to continue, debugger crashes.

Then i see in output, on browser just what was sent before the breakpoint.
If i not set a breakpoint, the page is comlpetely processed correctly.

i'm using:

Kubuntu 16.04

xdebug 2.4.0

PHP Version 7.0.8-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1

netbeans 8.1

this is my xdebug section  in php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="\tmp"
xdebug.idekey=XDEBUG_IDEKEY
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.collect_params=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=1000
xdebug.var_display_max_children=256
xdebug.var_display_max_data=4096
request_terminate_timeout=600s
```

i tried several different configuration in php.ini, always the same problem.

If ipaste my phpinfo() in https://xdebug.org/wizard.php
the result is:

> You're already running the latest Xdebug version

Does anyone have any idea?

Edit.

I added an error handler; that print this output:

```
Error: [8] Undefined variable: resq - xdebug://debug-eval:1
Terminating PHP Script
```

And inside the error handler i call:

debug_print_backtrace();

that print:

```
#0 handleError(8, Undefined variable: resq, xdebug://debug-eval, 1, Array ([_GET] => Array ([XDEBUG_SESSION_START] => netbeans-xdebug),[_POST] => Array (),[_COOKIE] => Array ([__utma] => 111872281.1893580102.1409742196.1409912396.1409912582.6,[_ga] => GA1.1.1893580102.1409742196,[HstCfa2834198] => 1442332630459,[HstCla2834198] => 1442821794939,[HstCmu2834198] => 1442332630459,[HstPn2834198] => 15,[HstPt2834198] => 51,[HstCnv2834198] => 5,[HstCns2834198] => 10),[_FILES] => Array (),[_ENV] => Array (),[_REQUEST] => Array ([XDEBUG_SESSION_START] => netbeans-xdebug),[_SERVER] => Array ([HTTP_HOST] => localhost,[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0,[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5,[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate,[HTTP_COOKIE] => __utma=111872281.1893580102.1409742196.1409912396.1409912582.6; _ga=GA1.1.1893580102.1409742196; HstCfa2834198=1442332630459; HstCla2834198=1442821794939; HstCmu2834198=1442332630459; HstPn2834198=15; HstPt2834198=51; HstCnv2834198=5; HstCns2834198=10,[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive,[PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin,[SERVER_SIGNATURE] =>
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
,[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu),[SERVER_NAME] => localhost,[SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1,[SERVER_PORT] => 80,[REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1,[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html,[REQUEST_SCHEME] => http,[CONTEXT_PREFIX] => ,[CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html,[SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@localhost,[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/fierart/index.php,[REMOTE_PORT] => 36736,[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1,[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1,[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET,[QUERY_STRING] => XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug,[REQUEST_URI] => /fierart/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug,[SCRIPT_NAME] => /fierart/index.php,[PHP_SELF] => /fierart/index.php,[REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1467579745.269,[REQUEST_TIME] => 1467579745))) called at [xdebug://debug-eval:1] #1 unknown() called at [/var/www/html/fierart/index.php:24]
```

thank you for helping.

Comment: xdebug.profiler_output_dir="\tmp" is wrong way round, but I don't think that is the issue

Comment: Infact, turn off the profiler and try again: xdebug.profiler_enable=0

Comment: Thank you for reply, i tried removing profiler_output_dir and setting profiler_enable= 0.
Changed nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function getAction() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867400/call-to-a-member-function-getaction-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved finding this topic

[Call to a member function getAction() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867400/call-to-a-member-function-getaction-on-a-non-object)

Problem was the same:

"I had an expression in my watch list i wasn't using anymore"

Comment: I edited this answer with what I thought was a solution from the post, but I think that was just a question addendum - apologies. I've reverted it.